# Grav - sort collection by date when date is in format 'd-m-Y' (30-11-2014 13:00)

Tags: twig, grav

I am using collections to sort list of blog entries:

```
---
title: Noticias
content:
    items: '@self.children'
    order:
        by: header.date
        dir: asc
    pagination: true
    limit: 10
---
```

All my page dates have the following format:

```
---
title: 'Test Page'
date: '15-09-2015 13:00'
taxonomy:
    category:
        - Noticias
---    
Content...
```

So the listing is done incorrectly, as `28-05-2005` goes after `15-05-2017`.

What shall be done in Grav to sort a collection taking into consideration date format? Specifically, sort entries using `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm` format?

Answer (score 0):

There's are a couple places you might be seeing this as a hangup

In your site configuration, you should have an entry for *Page date format*. The default is *Guess Automatically* which includes an option for the date you have shown in your example. Make sure that this is set to either *Guess Automatically* or the appropriate option.

The second option is within your page overrides. Go to the parent page (such as blog) and then click on the advanced tab. The first entry under *Overrides* is *Page date format*. Make sure this isn't checked, or that the selection is the date format you want.